# Query Report of time taken - combined report in ONE SQL

Tags: mysql

I have 100 queries to run in a single query and print the result as time taken

```
for example,
   select * from employee, select * from employee_address, select * from sales
```

How to combine all the queries and print the time taken with a single query?

Thanks

Comment: result as time taken? do you mean time taken to execute the queries?

Comment: yes Rinkesh. You are right and that is the expectation

Comment: @RinkeshP Can you please help me on the query?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html this should work for the time being although it will be deprecated, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html this is what you should follow.

Comment: @RinkeshP Thank you so much. Is it possible to SET and Query via API?

Comment: Add SELECT CURDATE(), NOW() to all the queries.....

But now sure whether it returns the time on each query or time at the end....

Can someone clarify this or suggest it?